# create client side java classes from a RESTful service in CXF

Tags: rest, cxf

I want to create client-side java from a restful web service, so that I can call the service. Do somebody know if CXF provide such this tools?

Best,

Answer (score 0):

With CXF 2.4.1, CXF does provide a "wadl2java" tool that can be used to create a Java client from a WADL document.   If your restful service provides a WADL, that can be used as a starting point.