# Scaffold for hateoas

Tags: javascript, hateoas

I have a hateoas api, and I was thinkig about if is there a way to automatically generate a javascript grid (as a ui) for the service?

Basically I'm looking for a scaffolding tool (like yeoman, or similar) which takes the hateos descriptor(s) as an input, and creates a bunch of js/html files for interacting with the data behind the API.

(I know, this won't be perfect - for example: validators - but something like this could greatly speed up the development)

Thanks,
krisy

Comment: You could try the REST Coder JavaScript/AJAX client stub generator, available on GitHub, and read the [documentation](http://restcoder.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html), but it seems that the project is no longer active.

You can also look at [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/restful-services.html), see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335358/java-tool-to-create-client-side-stubs-for-rest-service . But it's Java client-side stubs generation. 

Sorry for not having a real answer, I am interested in the topic.

I hope the answer will come with the W3C Hydra Core Vocabulary...